# Cannot mount /system as rw

Tags: adb, shell, mount, lineageos

I am rooted with magisk and while trying to mount /system as rw by using this command:

> mount -o remount, rw /system

There is an error

> '/system' not in /proc/mounts

Cat /proc/mounts returns:

```
ro,seclabel,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,size=963128k,nr_inodes=113081,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime,gid=3009,hidepid=2 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=963128k,nr_inodes=113081,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata /data f2fs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,background_gc=on,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,active_logs=6 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/fsg /fsg ext4 ro,context=u:object_r:fsg_file:s0,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nobarrier 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modem /firmware ext4 ro,context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nobarrier,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/persist /persist ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
adb /dev/usb-ffs/adb functionfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /storage tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=963128k,nr_inodes=113081,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /sbin tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=963128k,nr_inodes=113081 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /sbin/.core/mirror/system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata /sbin/.core/mirror/bin f2fs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,background_gc=on,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,active_logs=6 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /sbin/.core/img ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/framework/XposedBridge.jar ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/lib/libxposed_art.so ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/lib/libsigchain.so ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/lib/libart.so ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/lib/libart-disassembler.so ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/lib/libart-compiler.so ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/bin/patchoat ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/bin/oatdump ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/bin/dex2oat ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/bin/app_process32_xposed ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/etc/hosts ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/data/media /mnt/runtime/default/emulated sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6 0 0
/data/media /storage/emulated sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6 0 0
/data/media /mnt/runtime/read/emulated sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=23 0 0
/data/media /mnt/runtime/write/emulated sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7 0 0
/dev/block/vold/public:179_65 /mnt/media_rw/C583-170F vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/mnt/media_rw/C583-170F /mnt/runtime/default/C583-170F sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,mask=6 0 0
/mnt/media_rw/C583-170F /storage/C583-170F sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,mask=6 0 0
/mnt/media_rw/C583-170F /mnt/runtime/read/C583-170F sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,mask=18 0 0
/mnt/media_rw/C583-170F /mnt/runtime/write/C583-170F sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,mask=18 0 0
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata /sbin/.core/db-0/magisk.db f2fs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,background_gc=on,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,active_logs=6 0 0
```

I am on lineageos14.1 Merlin, Other apps like es file explorer can mount it correctly, but ADB shell cannot. please guide me on how to mount it as rw

Comment: Not sure why you're using Magisk - LOS has built-in lightweight root management which can be fully enabled with an additional patch. Tried the same command and it works on my own LOS device using built-in root. Suggestion is to backup and try built-in root with a clean flash - if that still doesn't work then the problem is device-specific.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find that root utility, but I want a single shell statement to work across multiple devices

Comment: The whole idea behind Magisk ist being systemLESS – i.e. NOT to modify `/system`. So maybe you [edit] your question and include what you want to achieve by mounting `/system` r/w? I somehow have the feeling this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154) to be solved in a different way.

Comment: Actually I am making an app that mounts the /system rw(kind of file manager) using a shell script so that I can edit system files. And since the script didn't work, I checked it in ADB shell and couldn't get it to work. I know magisk is all about systemless but other apps can mount my system rw whereas I can't even with the shell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so it was some typo issue, the correct command to mount it is:

> mount -o rw,remount /system

Comment: Wow, I used this command for years the other way around and it worked. Now I was struggeling on an new Android 8 device and this helped, I'm impressed.